# Copying pixels from an image to the webcam

Tags: java, image, converters, pixel, processing

What I am trying to do is to convert a pixel from a video cam, into an image
to expalin it better imagine a 3d model so.. the pixels would be each polying, and i want to do is to conver each polyigon into an image.

What i have so far is this:

```
**
import processing.video.*;
PImage hoja;
Capture cam;
boolean uno, dos, tres, cuatro;


import ddf.minim.*;

Minim minim;
AudioPlayer audio;
float set;



void setup() {

  //audio
  minim = new Minim(this);
 // audio = minim.loadFile("audio");
 // audio.loop();

//  
  uno=false;
  dos=false;
  tres=false;
  cuatro=true;
  size(640, 480);
  hoja=loadImage("hoja.gif");


    cam = new Capture(this, width, height);
    cam.start();

}

void draw() {
  if (cam.available() == true) {
    cam.read();

    if (uno==true) {
      filtroUno();
       image(cam, 0, 0, 640, 480);
       }
          if (dos==true) {
        filtroDos();
      }

      if(tres==true){
      filtroTres();
      }

      if(cuatro==true){
        filtroCuatro();
        image(cam, set, 0,640,480);
      }
  }


  // The following does the same, and is faster when just drawing the image
  // without any additional resizing, transformations, or tint.
  //set(0, 0, cam);
}

void filtroUno() {
  cam.loadPixels();
  hoja.loadPixels();
  for (int i=0;i<cam.pixels.length;i++) {
    if (brightness(cam.pixels[i])>110) {
      cam.pixels[i]=color(0, 255, 255);
    }
    else {
      cam.pixels[i]=color(255, 0, 0);
    }
  }

   for (int i=0;i<cam.width;i+=10) {

    for (int j=0;j<cam.height;j+=10) {
      int loc=i+(j*cam.width);
      if (cam.pixels[loc]==color(255, 0, 0)) {
        for (int x=i;x<i+10;x++) {
          for (int y=j;y<j+10;y++) {
            //  println("bla");
            int locDos=i+(j*cam.width);
            cam.pixels[locDos]=hoja.get(x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  cam.updatePixels();
}
**
```

The problem is that each pixel is creating me a matrix, so.. is not recreating what id that to do.

I had the method filtroUno but it wasn't showing ok..
and was the result

```
void filtroUno() {
  cam.loadPixels();
  hoja.loadPixels();
  for (int i=0;i<cam.pixels.length;i++) {
    if (brightness(cam.pixels[i])>110) {
      cam.pixels[i]=color(0, 255, 255);
    }
    else {
      cam.pixels[i]=color(255, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  for (int i=0;i<cam.width;i+=10) {

    for (int j=0;j<cam.height;j+=10) {
      int loc=i+j*hoja.width*10;
      if (cam.pixels[loc]==color(255, 0, 0)) {
        for (int x=i;x<i+10;x++) {
          for (int y=j;y<j+10;y++) {
            //  println("bla");
            int locDos=x+y*hoja.height*10;
            cam.pixels[locDos]=hoja.get(x, y);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  cam.updatePixels();
}
```

[image]

i hope you can help me thanks

note: each red pixel should be the gif image the imge size is 10x10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing is looping through every 10th pixel in a webcam image and if the pixel is red you are placing the contents of a 10x10px gif over the webcam image with the top left corner of the gif positioned at the pixel that was red.

```
// loop through each 10th column in the camera
for (int i=0;i<cam.width;i+=10) {

    // loop through each 10th row in the camera
    for (int j=0;j<cam.height;j+=10) {            

        // calculate the pixel location at (i, j)
        int loc=i+(j*cam.width);

        // check the pixel is red
        if (cam.pixels[loc]==color(255, 0, 0)) {

            // loop through each column in the gif image
            for (int x=0;x<10;x++) {

                // loop through each row in the gif image
                for (int y=0;y<10;y++) {

                    int locDos = (i + x) + ((j + y) * cam.width);
                    cam.pixels[locDos]=hoja.get(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```